# What is an essential discontinuity? Is it infinity or non-removable or infinite or oscillatory?

Tags: limits, continuity

I have been looking for examples of essential discontinuity but have been confused, as different sources cite different things. I know that it might be non-removable discontinuity and infinite and oscillatory are its types. Am I correct? Can somebody explain with examples?

Comment: Terminology like this can vary with the author. For me it helps to note that (for real-valued functions of a real variable) there are $5$ pointwise-defined values involved -- left lim-inf, left lim-sup, right lim-inf, right lim-sup, value of function at the point -- and all $5$ must be **finite** and equal for the function to be continuous at the point. The ways in which this can fail (some of the limits are infinite, some of the limits differ from each other or from the value of the function at the point, etc.) lead to various ways in which a function fails to be continuous.

Answer (score 3):

A definition of essential discontinuity that provides a good foundation to build an understanding upon is given in the work by John Klippert [[1]](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2689945.pdf). Therein, Klippert defines two "kinds" of essential discontinuities:

1. The **essential discontinuity of the first kind** occurs when *both* the right- and left-hand limits do not exist.
2. The **essential discontinuity of the second kind** occurs when *only* the right- *or* the left-hand limit does not exist.

Klippert takes the phrase "does not exist"<sup>†</sup>  to include the possibilities of $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

From these two definitions of the kinds of essential discontinuities, you can say that an **essential discontinuity** occurs whenever a one-sided limit does not exist: where a "one-sided limit" is taken to mean the right- or the left-hand limit.

Now, consider the definition of an infinite discontinuity. An **infinite discontinuity** occurs whenever a one-sided limit is $\pm \infty$. Thus, an infinite discontinuity is a type of essential discontinuity. More specifically:

- If *both* the right- and the left-hand limits are equal to $\pm \infty$, then the infinite discontinuity is an essential discontinuity of the *first kind*. For example, let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = -\infty$.
- If *only* the right- *or* the left-hand limit is equal to $\pm \infty$, then the infinite discontinuity is an essential discontinuity of the *second kind*. For example, let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ if $x>0$, else $f(x)=x$, then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = 0$.

Next, consider the definition of an oscillating discontinuity. An **oscillating discontinuity** occurs whenever a one-sided limit fails to exist at $x_0$ because the function $f(x)$ continues to oscillate as $x \to x_0^+$ or $x \to x_0^-$. Thus, an oscillating discontinuity is a type of essential discontinuity. More specifically:

- If *both* the right- and the left-hand limits do not exist because the function continues to oscillate as $x \to x_0$ from both the right and the left respectively, then the oscillating discontinuity is an essential discontinuity of the *first kind*. For example, let $f(x) = \sin (\frac{1}{x})$, then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)$ are both undefined.
- If *only* the right- *or* the left-hand limit does not exist because the function continues to oscillate as $x \to x_0$ from either the right or the left respectively, then the oscillating discontinuity is an essential discontinuity of the *second kind*. For example, let $f(x)=\sin (\frac{1}{x})$ if $x>0$, else $f(x)=x$, then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$ is undefined and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = 0$.

Finally, consider the definition of a non-removable discontinuity. A **non-removable discontinuity** occurs whenever the right- and left-hand limits are not equal to each other. If an essential discontinuity occurs whenever a one-sided limit does not exist, then because that one-sided limit does not exist, it cannot be said to be equal to the other, and therefore, it is a non-removable discontinuity. Thus, essential discontinuities of the first and second kind are a type of non-removable discontinuity.

#### Footnotes

<sup>†</sup> Note that saying that a limit does not exist is distinct from saying that the limit is $\pm \infty$. For example, saying that the $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = + \infty$ has a very precise meaning (namely that $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily large as $x$ approaches $x_0$). Whereas, saying that the $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \sin(x)$ does not exist does not also mean that it tends to infinity. Rather (obviously), the function continues to oscillate between $-1$ and $1$.

#### References

[1] J. Klippert, ‘Advanced advanced calculus: Counting the discontinuities of
a real-valued function with interval domain,’ Mathematics Magazine, vol. 62,
no. 1, pp. 43–48, Feb. 1989. [Online]. Available: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2689945.pdf.

Comment: *source of the term which is the work by John Klippert* --- The term "essential discontinuity" was used at least 100 years before Klippert's 1989 paper (e.g. see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fe7g69rdRCYC&pg=PA1652&dq=%22essential+discontinuity%22)). A better first sentence: "A nice way to understand essential discontinuities is given in a 1989 paper by John Klippert." (I changed "The best way" to "A nice way", because I can't imagine how one could actually determine "The best way"; in fact, even "The best known way" would probably take months of careful literature searching.)

Comment: Another useful discussion of the various types of discontinuities of a real-valued function of a real variable is [*The Discontinuities of Functions*](https://archive.org/details/theoryfunctreal01hobsrich/page/n303) (Articles 224-226 on pp. 283-286) of Hobson's **The Theory of Functions of a Real Variable** (Volume I, 2nd edition, 1921).

Comment: Appreciate the constructive feedback @DaveL.Renfro. I've updated the answer accordingly.